# Reactivate Account -- How to Delete Integer Type From Postgres Database Devise Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to allow the user to deactivate their account, and reactivate their account. I've got code which allows changes a is_active integer value to 0 when they deactivate the account.

I am using devise 3, rails 4 and postgres.

Here is my destroy method in **app/controllers/registration_controller.rb** which overrides devise's method and keeps the data in the database.

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user.is_active = 0
  if @user.save
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
    sign_out @user
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

Then I copied the idea and made a button for activating the account and used this code in the same registration controller:

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user.is_active == nil
  if @user.save
    set flash_message :notice
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

How can I set the is_active integer type back to a blank space?

Comment: Consider making is_active a boolean data type, default of true and set it to false as needed

Answer (score 1):

I think here's the problem:

```
@user.is_active == nil   #< -- conditional double =
```

should be

```
@user.is_active = nil   #< -- assignation
```